# Make flex item grow to available space, but keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to make flex items grow to the available space, but keep the aspect ratio? Here, I am having perfect squares, and I want to keep them as perfekt squares, but also make them grow to the vailable space that there is.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-content: center;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    row-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.card {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using the CSS `aspect-ratio` property:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-content: center;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    row-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.card {
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    border-radius: 2px;
    flex: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```